# Issue in Tiny MCE UI editor

Tags: angularjs, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have this editor on my code:

```
<textarea ui-tinymce="vm.viewModel.editorOptions" ng-model="vm.model.EmailTemplate"></textarea>
```

And the configuration:

```
vm.viewModel.editorModel.editorOptions = {
           selector: 'textarea',
           height: 400,
           theme: 'modern',
           plugins: [
             'advlist autolink lists link image preview hr anchor',
             'textcolor colorpicker textpattern'
           ],
           toolbar1: "undo redo | fontselect fontsizeselect | bold italic underline strikethrough | forecolor backcolor",
           toolbar2: "alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist | outdent indent blockquote | link unlink image | hr",
           image_advtab: true,
           menubar: false,
           statusbar: false,
       }
```

Now my problem is that the UI is not displaying right for the Add Image button. See screenshot

[image]

What am I missing here? I am adding the scripts like this below:

```
"~/Scripts/tinymce/tinymce.js",
"~/Scripts/ui-tinymce.js"
```

Comment: Do you have any custom CSS you are using?  (e.g. Bootstrap or otherwise)  Its possible that you have CSS that sets defaults that are overriding TinyMCE.